# Comparing Array Values in For Loop (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, compare, duplicates

I have a for loop and I want to compare each value to the other values in the array. If there are duplicates, the page redirects. How can I compare the value  `$name[$x]` to the other values in the $name array whether or not they come before or after `$name[$x]`?

```
for($x=0; $x<4; $x++) {
    if($name[$x] == /*Other members of $name*/) {
        header("location:../error/duplicates.php");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: array search my friend! http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: `if(in_array($name[$x],$array)...`

Comment: I'm not looking for the name to exist, I'm looking for its duplicate to exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you doing it like this:

```
for($x=0; $x<4; $x++) {
    if($name[$x] == /*Other members of array*/) {
        header("location:../error/duplicates.php");
        exit;
    }
}
```

When you could be use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/function.array-unique) instead:

```
if (count(array_unique($name)) < count($name)) {
  header("location:../error/duplicates.php");
  exit;
}
```

The logic is basically, the `array_unique` tells you how many unique items are in an array, right? And if the `$name` array contains 4 items, `count(array_unique())` should return 4. Which then should match the `count()` of the items in `$name`, right?  Well, if `count(array_unique())` has less items than `count()` it means duplicates were filtered out.

Here it is without the `header` but an `echo` instead as well as an `else` for simpler debugging.

```
$name = array('bob','betty','dan','don'); // no dupes
$name = array('bob','betty','dan','dan'); // dupes

if (count(array_unique($name)) < count($name)) {
  echo 'Dupes!';
  exit;
}
else {
  echo 'No Dupes!';
}
```

Also you could use [`array_diff_key`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) with [`array_unique`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). Basically do an `array_unique` on `$name` and then run that through `array_diff_key` comparing it to the original `$name`. if the `count` is greater than `0` then there is a dupe.

```
$name = array('bob','betty','dan','don'); // no dupes
$name = array('bob','betty','dan','dan'); // dupes

$name_diff = array_diff_key($name, array_unique($name));
if (count($name_diff) > 0) {
  echo 'Dupes!';
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($name_diff);
  echo '</pre>';
  exit;
}
else {
  echo 'No Dupes!';
}
```

**EDIT** I just edited the last suggestion to use a variable for `$name_diff` since if it does return a value more than `0` you now have that value in an array & can act on it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, You can use [`in_array`](http://www.php.net/in_array) php function

```
if (in_array($name[$x], $yourarray)) {
    echo $name[$x] ." Exist";
 }
```

For duplicate check:

```
 if(count($yourarry)> count(array_unique($name))){
    //found duplicate
 }
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm not looking for the name to exist in the array, I'm looking for its duplicate to exist in the array.